# find(1): "Parameter format not correct" under CygWin

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, cygwin

I'm trying to build Bochs from source. Therefore, I wrote an configure script. I didn't write my script from scratch - it's based on the  `.conf.win32-vcpp` sh script out of the Bochs tarball. And the part of the script, which causes the problem, is **out of the original** Nochs tarball **without any change** - I didn't write that part.

## My Problem:

Everytime I execute my sh script, the following error occurs:

```
[...]
config.status: creating host/linux/pcidev/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: creating ltdlconf.h
config.status: ltdlconf.h is unchanged
FIND: Parameterformat falsch
```

***** (*Parameterformat falsch* means *Parameter format not correct*)

But I don't need to execute the hall script. That rub fragment is enough:

```
sh-4.1$ find -name Makefile
FIND: Parameterformat falsch
```

***** (*Parameterformat falsch* means *Parameter format not correct*)

## My Questions:

- What's wrong with that script fragment: `find . -name Makefile`? Any idea?
- How can I rewrite that part of the code in order to make it work correctly?

## My Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set echo

./configure --target=pentium-windows \
            --enable-sb16 \
            --enable-ne2000 \
            --enable-all-optimizations \
            --enable-cpu-level=6 \
            --enable-x86-64 \
            --enable-pci \
            --enable-clgd54xx \
            --enable-usb \
            --enable-usb-ohci \
            --enable-show-ips \
            --enable-disasm \
            --enable-iodebug \
            --enable-logging \
            --enable-debugger-gui \
            --disable-readline \
            --without-x \
            --with-win32 \
            --with-rfb \
            --with-nogui \
            --with-wx

unset echo

# Fix up all makefiles so that nmake can handle them.
```

**-->** *Where the dog's buried:*

```
for i in `find . -name Makefile`; do
  echo Removing curly brackets in $i for NMAKE.
  mv $i $i.tmp
  sed -e 's/{/(/g' -e 's/}/)/g' < $i.tmp > $i
  rm -f $i.tmp
done
```

## My Environment:

I don't know if it matters, but I'm not using a normal bash. I use the shell provided by **cygwin**'s `sh` command (Win64).

Thanks.

Comment: In your test you are executing `find -name ...` without the `.` between `find` and `-name`.

Comment: What *exactly* is the command that fails (with or without `.`)? What does `type find` tell you? What about `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Both the command with `.` and without `.` fails. But `for i in \`find . -name Makefile\`` (with `.`) is the original from the Bochs tarball.

Comment: `echo $PATH` says `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live` [and so on ...]

Comment: @KeithThompson `type` says: `find is hashed (/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/find)`

Comment: @fridojet there's your problem -- it's running the Windows find, not the cygwin find.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Be sure your Cygwin installation includes the `findutils` package, and that Cygwin's `find` is first in your `PATH` (before the native Windows one).

If `find --help` returns `FIND: Paramater format not correct` (or your localized equivalent), this is a sure sign that it's the Windows one, rather than the Cygwin one, currently in use.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly my problem.